# GLFW cmake error on OSX with CLION

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glfw, clion

I have a very minimal project using `CMake` `GLEW` and `GLFW3` but for some reason `GLFW` when running `CMake` in `CLion` return with an error (shown below). I have the exact same version of my project running on Windows and it compiles and runs perfectly.

I originally had the source from [glfw3](http://www.glfw.org) but there is a bug in it for OSX where it errors on the FirstResponder but the code on GitHub seems to have fixed this issue so I have been using this package for a little while. Once I pulled my project from GitHub it seemed to have an issue with the code (windows uses the websites glfw3). My project on GitHub does not include the dependencies so the sharing between platforms (OSX and Windows) and the version differences should not have caused any errors as they are both completely separate.

hierarchy

- project source dir

  - Deps

    - glfw3
    - glew2
  - ...

cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(StormEngine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Engine/Logger/Logger.cpp Engine/Logger/Logger.h Engine/Engine.cpp Engine/Engine.h Engine/Window/Window.cpp Engine/Window/Window.h Engine/Helper/glfw_helper.h Engine/Events/Devices/Mouse.cpp Engine/Events/Devices/Mouse.h Engine/Events/Listeners/MouseManager.cpp Engine/Events/Listeners/MouseManager.h)
add_executable(StormEngine ${SOURCE_FILES})

#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/cmake")

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL  "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOl "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/glfw3)
target_link_libraries(StormEngine glfw)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/glfw3/include)


set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/glew2/include)
if (APPLE)
    set(GLEW_LIBRARY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/glew2/lib/libGLEW.2.0.0.dylib)
elseif(WIN32 OR WIN64)
    add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
    set(GLEW_LIBRARY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps/glew2/lib/Release/Win32/glew32s.lib)
endif()
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(StormEngine ${GLEW_LIBRARY})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(StormEngine ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

cmake error output

```
"/Users/Programmer/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/172.3317.49/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine
CMake Warning (dev) at Deps/glfw3/CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:

    GLFW_VERSION
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find Vulkan (missing:  VULKAN_LIBRARY VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Using Cocoa for window creation
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Programmer/CLionProjects/StormEngine/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

the output from glfw error callback after quitting the program (in the format of my log program). I am certain this is caused by the cmake problem, not from anything to do with my code as this does not occur on Windows which does not have the cmake errors.

```
ERROR [Engine.cpp][18]: GLFW3 code( 65537 ) -> The GLFW library is not initialized
```

Comment: I have the same warning but I think this is really just a warning. And it's probably only triggered on OSX because it has a different CMake version. In glfw3/CmakeLists.txt, you can add `cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)` to shut the warning off. You'll probably want to actually set the VERSION inside the project() command as well (versions are actually defined with the GLFW_ prefix a bit lower in the code). But you're probably using a submodule like me, so you'll have to fork your own glfw repository or you'll be unable to push your changes... Ideally, this should be PR-ed to the upstream repo.

Comment: And for your real error, have a look at where you call glfwInit, but I can't help you without more info.